# Force Logout in OneLogin does not send SAML Logout Request

Tags: onelogin, single-logout

I want to SSO/SLO from my native app, SSO works but SLO does not work.
I have Force Logouted the SAML initiator in the SSO configuration with both OneLogin and SP, but no SAML Logout Request is sent to my SLO endpoint.
SSO worked with either SAML initiator.

Is this a spec?
Is there any way to SLO with Force Logout?